# no android.mk file in Classes Folder for cocos2d-x 1.0.1-x-0.13.0-beta

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have problem with running build_native.sh in android cocos2d-x project. it turns out to be some linking problem. the cpp files that I created are not compiled and so become undefined reference.

here's the error :

```
SoybeanServer-2:android soybeansoft$ ./build_native.sh 
Using prebuilt externals
make: Entering directory `/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android'
SharedLibrary  : libgame.so
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: In function `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:111: undefined reference to `MainMenu::scene()'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld::okButtonCallback(cocos2d::CCObject*)':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:179: undefined reference to `Logic::select()'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld::newQuiz()':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:172: undefined reference to `Logic::getCurrentQuiz()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:173: undefined reference to `Logic::getCurrentQuiz()'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld::swipeRight()':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:151: undefined reference to `Logic::nextImage()'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld::swipeLeft()':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:145: undefined reference to `Logic::previousImage()'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `~HelloWorld':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Logic::unregisterEventHandler()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:30: undefined reference to `LogicEvent::~LogicEvent()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Logic::unregisterEventHandler()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:30: undefined reference to `LogicEvent::~LogicEvent()'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Logic::Logic()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Logic::Logic()'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld::imageChanged()':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:161: undefined reference to `Logic::getCurrentImage()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:162: undefined reference to `MemeImage::setImage(char const*)'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld::init()':
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:83: undefined reference to `MemeImage::MemeImage()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:90: undefined reference to `Logic::init(float)'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:91: undefined reference to `Logic::registerEventHandler(LogicEvent*)'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:93: undefined reference to `Logic::getCurrentQuiz()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:94: undefined reference to `Logic::getCurrentQuiz()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:96: undefined reference to `Logic::getCurrentQuiz()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:102: undefined reference to `Logic::getCurrentImage()'
/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android/jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:103: undefined reference to `MemeImage::setImage(char const*)'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x1d0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for LogicEvent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/Users/soybeansoft/devs/cocos2d-x_1.0/MemeQuiz/android'
SoybeanServer-2:android soybeansoft$
```

some people say that I need to list all the cpp files i created in Android.mk file in the Classes folder. But after I look out at the Classes folder, there's no Android.mk there.
so how should I list the .cpp files now?

Update :

I know that there's android.mk file in jni folder. but even if I list all my game cpp file there , the cpp still not compiled in the build_native process. So I really have no idea how to list my cpp files.

Comment: I found the problem! it's kind of importing error. well case closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android.mk file will be in the jni folder of the eclipse project. Look over there.

Comment: yeah I know there's one there. but the cpp files still not compile even if I list all my gamefile cpp there.

Comment: you might need to include the path to your cpp file, something like ../../Classes/Whatever.cpp

Comment: Yeah , I a facing the another similar problem.Actually I am not adding more classes but I am modifying the code in the classes. Changes are not being applied and after importing this project , I have seen some errors present in main.cpp on jni folder.